# Visual Studio Extension Mouse Button events not working

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have a Visual Studio extension with a (async) tool window. The tool window has an `UserControl`, and the control has an `Image` which I use `WriteableBitmap` as a source. Basically, I am trying to use a graphics API (Vulkan) on a tool window.

Basically, my extension could look something similar to Visual Studio's 3d model editor.

My problem here is that none of mouse event handlers like `MouseLeftButtonDown` or `PreprocessMouseLeftButtonDown` gets called when I click on the tool window. I have tried adding a mouse event handler to the `UserControl`, `Image`, and even `HwndHost`, but I had no success.

I am aware of `IMouseProcessor` or other variants, but it seems to me, that they are used for text editors, not just a tool window pane or a user control.

`HwndHost`'s `WndProc` method does not seem to receive any mouse events either. Simply "cheesing" it by replacing parent Hwnd's WndProc seems to work, but I did not want to create an extension that takes control of the entire Visual Studio.

**== EDIT ==**

```cs
public partial class MyControl : UserControl {
    public MyControl () {
        InitializeComponents ();
        MouseLeftButtonDown += MyLeftButtonDown;
    }
    ...
    private void MyLeftButtonDown (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        // This code never gets executed.
    }
}
```

Nor these.

```xml
<UserControl ...
             IsHitTestVisible="True"
             MouseLeftButtonDown="MyLeftButtonDown ">
    <Image x:Name="View" ... />
    <!--- nor this --->
    <!--- <Image x:Name="View" MouseLeftButtonDown="MyLeftButtonDown " /> --->
</UserControl>
```

This also doesn't work.

```cs
public partial class MyControl : UserControl {
    public MyControl () {
        InitializeComponents ();
        // View is an object of Image class.
        View.MouseLeftButtonDown += MyLeftButtonDown;
    }
    ...
    private void MyLeftButtonDown (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        // This code never gets executed.
    }
}
```

```
// C++/CLI
IntPtr MyHost::WndProc (IntPtr hWndPtr, int uMsg, IntPtr wParamPtr, IntPtr lParamPtr, bool % handled)
{
    auto hWnd = (HWND) hWndPtr.ToPointer ();
    auto wParam = (WPARAM) wParamPtr.ToPointer ();
    auto lParam = (LPARAM) lParamPtr.ToPointer ();

    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: // This doesn't get called.
            break;
        ...
        default:
            handled = false;
            return IntPtr (DefWindowProc (hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam));
    }
    ...
    handled = true;
    return IntPtr (0);
}
```

Comment: Can you please [share a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us and any other detailed info will be expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not figured out how to process mouse inputs with `Image` or `UserControl` yet, but I figured it out for `HwndHost`.

Apparently, if your `HwndHost` is not replying to `WM_NCHITTEST`, then your `HwndHost` will never received any mouse events like `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`.

```
// C++/CLI
IntPtr MyHost::WndProc (IntPtr hWndPtr, int uMsg, IntPtr wParamPtr, IntPtr lParamPtr, bool % handled)
{
    auto hWnd = (HWND) hWndPtr.ToPointer ();
    auto wParam = (WPARAM) wParamPtr.ToPointer ();
    auto lParam = (LPARAM) lParamPtr.ToPointer ();

    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_NCHITTEST: // This message.
            SetFocus (hWnd);
            handled = true;
            return IntPtr (HTCLIENT);
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: // This works now.
            break;
        ...
        default:
            handled = false;
            return IntPtr (DefWindowProc (hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam));
    }
    ...
    handled = true;
    return IntPtr (0);
}
```

And then, you can put some delegates or events and call them for `WndProc` messages.